# Remove an element that was added via $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which adds rows via a `fa-plus` button. I'm looking to remove the row via a `fa-minus` button.

```
(function(angular) {


 'use strict';
   angular.module('app').directive('addSearchRow', addSearchRow);
   function addSearchRow($compile) {
     return {
       controller: function($scope, elm, scope) {
         $scope.removeSearchRow = function() {
           console.log('removeSearchRow');
           //$scope.$destroy();
           elm.after($compile('')(scope));
         };
       },
       link: function (scope, elm) {
         scope.addSearchRow = function(){
           console.log(elm);
           elm.after($compile('<add-search-row ng-model="data.advancedSearchType"></add-search-row>')(scope));
         };
       },
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<div class="input-group-btn advanced-search-select-group"><select class="form-control cat-1"><option ng-repeat="advancedSearchType in advancedSearchType" value="{{advancedSearchType.name}}" ng-bind="advancedSearchType.name"></option></select><select class="form-control cat-2"><option ng-repeat="isIsNot in isIsNot" value="{{isIsNot.name}}" ng-bind="isIsNot.name"></option></select><input type="text" class="form-control advanced"/><a ng-click="removeSearchRow()" class="clickable advanced"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a><a ng-click="addSearchRow()" class="clickable advanced"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>',
     };
   }

 })(angular);
```

My thoughts were that I needed to destroy the element but I'm not so sure the best approach. What is the best way to remove elements from the DOM that have been added via `$compile`? Ideally I'd like to use the same directive.

Comment: The approach is not right. Instead of compiling new elements, you should simply push/pop elements from an array, and render this array as HTML using `ng-repeat` in your directive template.

Comment: @floribon I was just writing up a comment that essentially says the same thing. `$compile` should be a last resort for most implementations

Comment: I think there are cases where compiling and adding children is a valid use case. We shouldn't assume this case (or some future reader's) isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about this not being the right approach. I'm going to give the push/pop a shot. Any reasoning behind $compile being a last resort?

Comment: @fauverism because adding and removing elements from the DOM is exactly what ngRepeat does (or ngIf when there is only one). As much as possible, Angular wants you to separate concerns, the controllers/links should contain the model states (no notion of html), and the templates render that into HTML. But of course you need essential bricks, and 90% of the time the built-in directives are enough for that (ng-bind, ng-if, ng-show, ng-repeat, ng-include, etc)